# How to dispose FocusNode and TextEditingController inside a Dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a **Dialog** which takes input from two Text-Fields and do some task based on the click of Button.
To handle the focus and input from those text-fields i have created **FocusNode** and **TextEditingControllers**.

Normally in **State** of StatefulWidget, we have dispose method in which we can dispose the **ChangeNotifier**, But i think thats not directly possible in case of dialogs.

So, should I avoid diposing those changeNotifiers or instead of building widget anonymously inside of showDialog() i should create a seperate class of StateFulWidget?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Create a separate class and make it `StatefulWidget`;
2. in the State class use `dispose()` to dispose your controllers.

Note: avoid having complex code inside of an anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i create dialog with simple textInput and one button ,when user click on button dispose edittext programitically

```
class MyDialogs {
   bool showed = false;
   void dismiss(BuildContext context) {
     if (showed) {
       Navigator.pop(context);
     }
  }

 void showCaptcha(
    BuildContext context,
    ) {
   String? errorText;
showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      showed = true;
      const Color accentColor = Colors.teal;

      TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
        return Dialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [

                    Container(
                        width: 360,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: editingController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: 'Enter seen text',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ))),

                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        backgroundColor: accentColor,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                              'authorize   ',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.security,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        {
                          String text = editingController.text;

                          if (text.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              errorText = 'please enter seen text';
                            });
                            return;
                          }

                          editingController.dispose();

                          dismiss(context);

                          // if (onClicker != null) {}
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ));
      });
    });
```

}
}